# Leveling web parts on a page on two different columns

Tags: web-part, page-layout

I have been fighting with this for about 3 hours now and I can't find any reason for it online.

The issue I am having is I am putting the same two web parts side by side using the two column layout on a SharePoint page. No matter what I do though the two web parts are not even. Is there any reason for this?

What I want _   _

What I am getting -  _

Comment: What webparts are you using? Any custom CSS / Javascripts affecting the page?

Comment: @RobertLindgren No. It is a basic page with the header and two column layout. Nothing custom at all.

Comment: try adding a fixed width or display:inline-block to the outer most div of the webpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs for site pages. When you change the page to Two Column layout, SharePoint (for some unknown reason) automatically adds a space to the second column. When you insert your web part this space pushes down your web part with a line.

Try to delete this space from above the web part when the page is in edit mode.

If it does not help, then delete both web parts, change back to One Column layout and to Two Column layout again. Then delete the space from the second column before adding the web parts.